# Can't upgrade dart sdk

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code to practice the Dart language (not flutter, I'm using Android Studio for that). My file's name is main.dart. Anyways, VS Code keeps telling me to upgrade Dart to the latest version.

Whenever I do, the command prompt/Powershell informs me that access to path 'dart.exe' is denied, specifically C:\tools\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe.

How do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upgrade dart SDK using flutter console:

1- Head to your flutter SDK folder path ( where you downloaded flutter SDK).

2- Open flutter console and type `flutter upgrade --force`.

This will upgrade both flutter and dart SDKs

Answer (score 0):

you can upgrade dart sdk by using flowing command:

**In Windows**

```
choco upgrade dart-sdk
```

**In Linux**
If you’re using Debian/Ubuntu on AMD64 (64-bit Intel), you can choose one of the following options, both of which can update the SDK automatically when new versions are released.

Install using apt-get
Install a Debian package
Install using apt-get
Perform the following one-time setup:

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
 sudo sh -c 'wget -qO- https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -'
 sudo sh -c 'wget -qO- https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian/dart_stable.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dart_stable.list'
```

Then install the Dart SDK:

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install dart
```

Install a Debian package
Alternatively, download Dart SDK as Debian package in the .deb package format.

Modify PATH for access to all Dart binaries
After installing the SDK, add its bin directory to your PATH. For example, use the following command to change PATH in your active terminal session:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/dart/bin"
```

To change the PATH for future terminal sessions, use a command like this:

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/dart/bin"' >> ~/.profile
```

**For more details visit this link:**
https://dart.dev/get-dart

Comment: As I've mentioned, my problem is I can't upgrade it because access is denied. How do I accept access?